# MS ACCESS: How to lookup environ username in a table in MS Access so that the full name is returned in a textbox?

Tags: vba, ms-access, lookup

Application: MS ACCESS

1: I used this code found in Stackoverflow (thank you!) to get the username of the current user of the dbase. the problem is I need to lookup the username in the table named "VCUsers" to get the 
"Participant".

2: This is the "VCUsers" table. The username and its corresponding "Participant" is listed here. How do I lookup the username I got via VBA from this table so that the "Participant" shows up in the "User" text box in the home page?

3: This is the Home Page and the User text box at the upper left.

[See screenshots here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMzUT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a VBA Function:

```
Public Function GetFullName() As String
    GetFullName = DLookUp("Participant", "VCUsers", "[User ID]='" & Environ$("username") & "'")
End Function

'=GetFullName()
```

When the form loads:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.YourTextBoxName.Value = DLookUp("Participant", "VCUsers", "[User ID]='" & Environ$("username") & "'")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much I am going to try these out now. I have a follow up question though... Which do you think is the best way to go? Directly in the Record Source or VBA? (I don't have prior ms access knowledge so sorry for the question...)

Comment: Hello I tried adding it to the record source but i am getting an error: "The record source '=DlookUp ...")' specified on this form or report does not exist. What I did was copy the code you gave me and pasted it directly to the record source property. am i doing something wrong?

Comment: What does the error say? Try one of the VBA options to see if you get the error.

Comment: It says: "The record source '=DlookUp ...")' specified on this form or report does not exist. What I did was copy the code you gave me and pasted it directly to the record source property. am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Hmm... I believe the `Environ("username")` function is causing the issue. Try one of the VBA options/

Comment: Hello @Kostas K. I am so happy the VBA method worked!!! I don't know how to thank you enough for this!!! I have no knowledge in MS Access yet I was tasked to do it here at work and I thought I was on a dead end. This means so much to me and the people who will eventually use the dbase. With all my heart, THANK YOU!